# How do you remove some array from foreach

Tags: php

i'm trying to remove some array from foreach 
example for "result" array :

```
    $result= array (  
  "1"  => array(
    "nickname" => "Jow",
    "Age"=> "19"
    ),
        "2"  => array(
    "nickname" => "Rayan",
    "Age"=> "25"
    ),
        "3"  => array(
    "nickname" => "Jinx",
    "Age"=> "21"
    ),
    );
```

**i want remove array 1 by nickname** 
mycode :

```
foreach ($result as $client => $value){

if ( $value["nickname"] == "Jow"){

    unset($result[$client]);

    }
echo $value["nickname"].'<p>';

}
```

Eventually i want The remaining names like Rayan and Jinx

Comment: check out `array_filter`

Comment: @RodrigoDuterte Oi! You're here. Election is near. Is change really coming?

Comment: @rhavendc yes change is **really** coming

Comment: @suibber remove array 1 by name

Comment: @RodrigoDuterte i not understand what you say and i test echo (array_filter($resultt,"Jow"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use array_filter ?

```html
$result= array (  
  "1"  => array(
    "nickname" => "Jow",
    "Age"=> "19"
    ),
        "2"  => array(
    "nickname" => "Rayan",
    "Age"=> "25"
    ),
        "3"  => array(
    "nickname" => "Jinx",
    "Age"=> "21"
    ),
);

$arr = array_filter($result, 'filter_by_name');
var_dump($arr);exit;

function filter_by_name($value){
 if ($value['nickname']=='Jow') {
  return false;
 } else {
  return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: or just `return $value['nickname'] != 'Jow''`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
function removeByNickName($nickName, $array)
{
    $temp = array();
    foreach($array as $index => $ar)
    {
        if($array['nickname'] != $nickName) array_push($temp, $ar);
    }
    return $temp;
}
```